# How to read properties file in Controller using annotations only? Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to read properties file in Controller using annotations only?

Properties file contains (env.properties):

```
 document.portal.path=http://flana.gost.com/service
```

Spring Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/kap/*")
@SessionAttributes({"user", "KapForm", "activity"})
public class KapController {
@Value("${document.portal.path}")
private String URL; 
}
```

Nothing else is done. In XML, we use to use placeholder, which i am not getting how to introduce in it. So I am getting exception.

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
```

Comment: Have you declared  `util:properties` for `env.properties` in your bean definition file?

Comment: if you could post your config file, it would be easy to help you

Comment: @xyz:
There is no config file. It is all annotations. I don't know where to declare util:properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in two ways

**Option 1**

In config class put `@PropertySource` and define a bean for `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as below -

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:someFile.properties")
public class SampleConfig { 

    // other configs...

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

In config class directly specify the bean for `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and supply the name of property file as `ClassPathResource`

```
@Configuration
public class SampleConfig {

    // other configs...

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer(){
      PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
      ClassPathResource[] cpResources = new ClassPathResource[]
              { new ClassPathResource( "someFile.properties" ) };
      placeHolderConfigurer.setLocations(cpResources);
      placeHolderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
      return placeHolderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Do note that the bean definition for place holder need to be `static` as per [java docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) (*excerpts below*)

> Special consideration must be taken for `@Bean` methods that return Spring `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` (BFPP) types. Because BFPP objects must be instantiated very early in the container lifecycle, they can interfere with processing of annotations such as `@Autowired`, `@Value`, and `@PostConstruct` within `@Configuration` classes. To avoid these lifecycle issues, mark BFPP-returning `@Bean` methods as **static**.

Comment: Thanks. Can i make inner class in controller for the same and use in outer class? As this is to be used in one controller only? Best is if i can autowire as shown above as this paradigm is followed in other module.

Answer (score 0):

Another way out found is

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
cutiePie = messageSource.getMessage("cutie.pie.property", new Object[] {},"cutie.pie.property", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```